# Double Omelette pan?

Tags: omelette

My husband wants an omelette pan that will allow him to make 2 omelettes at the same time. Does such a thing exist? I have come up empty in my searches. Anybody have a solution for me?

Comment: How does he prepare the omelette?   What is his vision of the pan?

Comment: Two of whatever single pan he uses would seem simplest and least requiring any change in technique. At the other end of the scale, a commercial flat-top grill, which will almost certainly involve a change in technique, but can easily do 6 or more at once.

Comment: ... do they make a pan in the shape of a figure-8?

Comment: There are strange hinged 'omelette' pans that let you cook scrambled eggs in a vaguely folded omelette shape.  I don't know if you're expected to cook eggs on both sides, then add filling and flip one into the other, or if you mix the filling in with eggs on one side, and then flip it to the other to finish cooking (which could then be used to cook 2 at once).  Personally, if I'm cooking for a crowd, I make a frittata instead.

Comment: Oh, dear god.  It's not just 'As Seen on TV' brands.  NordicWare has two ([one for folded](https://www.amazon.com//dp/B0055FSODU), [one for rolled](http://www.williams-sonoma.com/products/nordic-ware-rolled-omelette-pan/)).  Cuisinart has a [2 pan set that lock together for flipping](https://www.amazon.com//dp/B0078P9D5S/) (more useful for tortilla de patatas ... and useful for cooking other things, too).  A [NordicWare video shows the hinged one used both ways that I mentioned above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQM7BRI-KmE).

Comment: I can't imagine how making 2 omelettes at the same time would work. Once the omelette has come together, you have about 15 seconds to get it to the plate. You just don't have enough hands to get them ready at the same time, and the timing is too short to leave one on the fire while plating the other.

Comment: I think the biggest challenge logistically with making two omelettes in the same pan is trying to cook two circular omelettes in a circular pan. Usually the edges of the pan provide the circular edge that stops the egg from running even wider. I think you have two options: two of the exact same pan, or one big pan that makes one big omelette for two to share.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative suggestion for producing multiple omelets (rather than [frittatas](http://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-a-frittata-and-an-omelet-word-of-mouth-216451)) at once would be to get a [griddle pan](https://www.amazon.com/Lodge-LPGI3-Reversible-Griddle-10-44-inch) or [electric griddle](https://www.amazon.com/BLACK-DECKER-GD2011B-Electric-22-Inches) and then he'd have to [learn to cook on a flat top](https://youtu.be/rVj_AtRF6PM), which would probably only take a short time.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, such a thing does exist. It is called Better Chef Non-Stick Double Omelette Or Frittata Maker - No Pans Mess Fuss. This would serve as a great present for your husband.

[image: Better Chef Non-Stick Double Omelette Or Frittata Maker--an all in one clamshell design griddle with two wells for cooking multiple omelettes at the same time.]